# Typescript error '0' not assignable to type QueryKey

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type DateRange = { start: Date; end: Date }
  type ParamType = {
    latitude: number | null | undefined
    longitude: number | null | undefined
    term: string
    dateRange: DateRange
  }

  const params: ParamType = {
    latitude: geo && geo.lat,
    longitude: geo && geo.lng,
    term,
    dateRange,
  }

  type QueryKey = (ParamType | string)[] | null | undefined
  const key: QueryKey = geo && geo.lat && geo.lng && ['all-results-cts', params]
```

Typescript throws error `'0' not assignable to type QueryKey` for `key` variable assignment. whats the issue with the code?

Comment: please provide reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here -

```
type QueryKey = (ParamType | string)**[]** | null | undefined
```

`0` not assignable for type array or null or undefined.
`(ParamType | string)**[]**` type is for array of (ParamType | string) types.
You need to check type that get to key variable and fix it or adjust QueryKey with **string** type.

```
type QueryKey = (ParamType | string)**[]** | null | undefined | string
```